# Keyboard bounces up and down in flatlist (react native)

Tags: react-native

This issue is driving me crazy, I'm using a flatlist to render data to a list.

Each listitem has text that is editable and when I press them a keyboard comes up which allows me to edit each item. However, even though I've added keyboardavoidingview - on android, if the list is taking up the whole page, it wont let me edit the last items in the list.
When I press them the keyboard just bounces up and then down again, like it's trying to push everything up but it doesn't have enough space or something. I've tried what feels like everything, changing flex-settings, behavior and keyboardVerticalOffset to every possible value.

I won't post the whole code because it might be to messy, but my question is: has anyone encountered the same issue and knows what is messing it up?

(to emphasize, I only have this issue on android, in all kind of screen sizes)

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 40 : -10}>
```

Comment: Is it the same issue ? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28246

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you removeClippedSubviews={false} in the flatlist solved it for me.  You can post the answer if you want to so I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `removeClippedSubviews={false}` in the FlatList works for some React-Native versions